# Issue on add-migration in this current bridging class (many-to-many)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Currently, we have this model - HostApplicationUser and it's bridging for Many-To-Many relationship between **Host** and **ApplicationUser** (extended from IdentityUser).

```
public class HostApplicationUser
{
    public Guid HostID { get; set; }

    public Host Host { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

}
```

An in our, ApplicationDBContext we modified the protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) to include as follow:

```
// Many to Many relationships

            builder.Entity<HostApplicationUser>()
                .HasKey(bc => new { bc.HostID, bc.Id });


            builder.Entity<HostApplicationUser>()
                .HasOne(bc => bc.Host)
                .WithMany(b => b.HostApplicationUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.HostID);

            builder.Entity<HostApplicationUser>()
                .HasOne(bc => bc.ApplicationUser)
                .WithMany(c => c.HostApplicationUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.Id);
```

This code has been running ok. BUT now we have a new requirement to add few properties/navigation as follow:

```
public class HostApplicationUser
{
    public Guid HostID { get; set; }

    public Host Host { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedUTC { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastModifiedUTC { get; set; }

    public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeletedUTC { get; set; }

    public string DeletedBy { get; set; }

    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationCreatedUser { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LastModifiedBy")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationLastModifiedUser { get; set; }

}
```

Then we have an error when we run the add-migration:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'HostApplicationUser.ApplicationCreatedUser' of type 'ApplicationUser'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Any ideas on how to adjust fix this? I believe this something to do with OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) to include the other navigation but not sure how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The reason

The reason is that **there're multiple navigation properties on the dependent and principal entities pairs**. Considering the following relationships between `HostApplicationUser` and `ApplicationUser` :

1. `ApplicationUser`  `<->`  `HostApplicationUser.ApplicationUser`
2. `ApplicationUser`  `<->`  `HostApplicationUser.ApplicationCreatedUser`
3. `ApplicationUser`  `<->`  `HostApplicationUser.ApplicationLastModifiedUser`
4. ... and a potential relationship for `DeletedBy`

If you have an navigation property to `HostApplicationUser` on `ApplicationUser` :

```
public class ApplicationUser{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public IList<HostApplicationUser> HostApplicationUsers{get;set;} 
}
```

And if there's no extra configuration , the `EF Core` cannot  determine whether the `Application.HostApplicationUsers` property is `CreatedUsers` , `LastModifiedUsers`, `DeletedUsers` or something other users, i.e., **the `EF Core` cannot  determine how the `ApplicationUser.HostApplicationUsers` property is navigated to `HostApplicationUser`**, thus complains :

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'HostApplicationUser.ApplicationCreatedUser' of type 'ApplicationUser'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

#### How to fix

To fix the issue, simply decorate the `ApplicationUser.HostApplicationUsers` with an **`InversePropertyAttribute`** :

```
public class ApplicationUser{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [InverseProperty("ApplicationUser")]
    public IList<HostApplicationUser> HostApplicationUsers{get;set;} 
}
```

Or if would like to have multiple navigation properties, you need to add `[InverseProperty("ApplicationCreatedUser")]`,`[InverseProperty("ApplicationLastModifiedUser")]`,`[InverseProperty("ApplicationDeletedUser")]` and so on for each navigation property :

```
public class ApplicationUser{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [InverseProperty("ApplicationUser")]
    public IList<HostApplicationUser> HostApplicationUsers{get;set;} 

    [InverseProperty("ApplicationCreatedUser")]
    public IList<HostApplicationUser> HostApplicationCreatedUsers{get;set;}

    [InverseProperty("ApplicationLastModifiedUser")]
    public IList<HostApplicationUser> HostApplicationLastModifiedUsers{get;set;}

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Why should be IList<ApplicationUser> ... can this be just ApplicationUser only ?

Comment: Never thought about the co-creators in this case. Good point! Will try this InverseProperty.

Comment: @dcpartners Do yo mean the `IList<HostApplicationUser>`  ?

Comment: @dcpartners The original relationship between `Host` and `ApplicationUser` is `Many-to-Many` through `HostApplicationUser`, and can be transformed to  two `One-to-Many` relationships : `HostApplicationUser: ApplicationUser` and `HostApplicationUser: Host` .  A `HostApplicationUser` will have exact one `ApplicationUser`, and a `ApplicationUser` might have multiple `HostApplicationUser` ( own , create, modify, or delete many hosts).

Comment: Continuing with this. I have other model ie. **Host** which has CreatedBy and LastModifiedBy as well and has navigation to ApplicationUser ... would this `[InverseProperty("ApplicationCreatedUser")]` and `[InverseProperty("ApplicationLastModifiedUser")]` affecting this?

Comment: @dcpartners No. The [`InverserProperty("ApplicationLastModifiedUser")]` is decorated on `ApplicationUser.HostApplicationLastModifiedUsers`, it will only affect the relationship between  `ApplicationUser.HostApplicationLastModifiedUsers` and `HostApplicationUser.ApplicationLastModifiedUser`